# scrollTo inside an Accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, scrollto

I'm trying very hard to attach a scrollTo inside an accordion, but it seems, if the the former works the latter stop working, vice versa.

Here's what I want to achieve,

http://www.ge-energy.com/

and here's my code that I wrote for this

http://jsfiddle.net/ztFWv/51/

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9NW/1/

Its thrown together fairly quickly but with some modifications it could do the job.

It makes use of the JQuery UI accordian as well as the JQuery [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin.

Hope it helps.

**Edit (Based on comments)**

Needed some modifications to the javascript. Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var itemWidth = 400;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').width($(document).width()-10);
    $("#accordion").accordion({ fillSpace: true });

    $('#accordion> h3').click(function () {
        var index = ($('h3').index(this));
        $('#container').scrollTo((index * itemWidth).toString() + 'px', 800);
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">

#accordion
{
    width:200px;
    font-size:12px;
}

#navigation
{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:15px;
    height:300px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#container
{
    width:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#items
{
    width:2000px;
}

.item
{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#a9a9a9;
    text-align:left;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="navigation">
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
        amet, nunc.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
        purus. Vivamus hendrerit.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
        Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
        ac tellus pellentesque semper.
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
        et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
        faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
        mauris vel est.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>     
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="items">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://businesstm.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/mlm-downline-building.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.socalfools.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/The-importance-of-advertising-in-the-marketing-business.jpg">
        </div>        
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.rhylbusinessgroup.co.uk/admin/Image/grey_business_group.jpg">         
        </div>        
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.businesscrm.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/Sales-Automation.jpg">
        </div>        
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.aworldafilm.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Selecting-the-Right-Online-Business.jpg">
        </div>              
    </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem with this one [http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9NW/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9NW/4/) is your html section. It contains references to files which do not exist as well as duplicate javascript. When removed it works the same as my example: [http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9NW/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9NW/1/)

Comment: The scripts are already included (see the manage resources area on the left) and any css you want to include can be added in the css pane on the right.

Comment: no, i copied all that from my text editor, the thing is it is working fine in jsfiddle, but when I copy all the codes into my text-editor with correct references to files, it does not work. while if i provide correct references in jsfiddle, it's working perfectly fine.

i'm using firefox and IE, it's not working in either one if you open the file from the text editor.

Comment: like here, http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9NW/6/ 

this is working perfectly fine, including all the correct references, but when I copy all this into my Dreamweaver or other text editors, the accordion is working but the scroll is not.

Comment: still a no show with the scroll :S 

pardon me for my noobness, i'm totally new to this stuff :S

Comment: For me it works fine. Possibly the problem is that your screen is wide enough so that no scrolling is needed. Try resizing your browser so that it is the width of two of the images and then reloading the page.

Comment: works, at last. 

perfectly fine now :)

answer up for those quick responses :)

Comment: a problem that i'm having right now is that, when i attach all the codes and everything to my HTMl and everything, i'm getting a scrollable width. i do not want he scrollbar, what should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Can you replicate it using jsfiddle? If so why don't you post another question and either I or someone else can take a look for you.

Comment: it was related about the same thing, so i thought i should post it here. it's the same jsfiddle that you made above, it's just that i do not want the window to be scrollable. i want it to fit in the pane, only that picture should show which has it's tab opened, rest should be hidden and would show once their tabs are clicked.

Comment: It really depends on the width specified for the container div element. In the example below (see fiddle link) I have specified the width to be the same as each image (400px) and removed the js code on load to resize it to the width of the browser. If you wanted to have larger images you would need to adjust the width of the container element to the width  of the image (each image would need to be the same width) and set the width of the image in the variable (itemWidth) Here is the fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9NW/24/](http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9NW/24/). See comments in the fiddle.

Comment: sorry to bug to that much, there's another problem in it, which is that. 

after the first image, when i click the second tab, the second tab's respective image goes up by like 10px ?

Comment: Try this: [http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9NW/26/](http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9NW/26/). I have increased the height of each item (see comment above .item css class)

Comment: i did the same, but when you go through the whole navigation, and come back, it jumps again upwards.

also i do not want the navigation to be over the images, like i have set 2 divs. one for nav and one for img, and have floated each left and right. so i want the right one to be separate from the nav bars and img to be be fully viewable

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to `.animate()` the background position property on item select.

```
 $('#myBackgroundImage').animate({
          backgroundPosition: -4000 /* whatever you want */
    }, 1000, function()
    {
       alert('Animation Complete');
    });
```

Comment: can you please provide an example in jsfiddle, as i'm totally new to these things. do not know much abou jquery :)